# Users don't see their tag score on `tags/[tag]/topusers` if score is negative

Tags: support, score, tag-score

I've noticed that users don't see their tag score on `tags/[tag]/topusers` if score is 0 or negative. Is that by design or a bug?

E.g., on my side, I don't see myself on https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/swift/topusers, even though I have `0` for answers and `-2` for questions (as shown by searching for [`user:5656 [swift] is:question`](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A5656+%5Bswift%5D+is%3Aquestion)).

Comment: I'd be surprised if that *isn't* by design.  You're not a top user, so you shouldn't be listed.

Comment: @Ollie the user is listed if the score is strictly positive, regardless of how it compares to others

Comment: @Rob only answers are counted for the badges I believe

Comment: I see, your fairly high reputation is mostly from questions; I was thinking that it wasn't updating for you, but I was looking at the wrong tab. --- As to this question: Most people would have **0** for most tags, IE: they didn't participate in the tag by answering a question; if everyone with zero had to be counted how would the *top* (bottom) users be chosen to add to the limited length Top Users list. 2ndly, if you have a negative score then you're in the hole, you'd need to improve just to match someone who didn't even answer; so that's (probably) why negative isn't tallied either.